# How can I download a file using Selenium in Python that is only accessible through the Chrome inspect tool's "Sources" tab?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the process of downloading a file using Selenium in Python. However, I am having trouble finding the file using regular selectors. The only way I can seem to locate it is by using the Chrome inspect tool and navigating to the "Sources" tab, as shown in the attached screenshot.

Is there a way to automate this process using Selenium and Python? How can I locate and download this file using Selenium when it can only be found through the inspect tool?

[image: Screenshot]

I tried to search the driver.source for the information but it is not in there

I also tried to opening the developer tools like this

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs")
```

and then tried using code like this to navigate it

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'[aria-label="Sources"]').click()
```

but this is also not working

Any help navigating this issue would be greatly appreciated
`